# Somar valores de uma coluna no banco de dados através de filtro de data

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Preciso somar todos os valores de uma coluna contendo em cada linha uma data específica, ou seja, no banco de dados, os valores são salvos com a data digitada no `textBox` no ato do cadastro, e preciso somar todos os valores da coluna `quantidadeVagas`. Assim quando o usuário digita uma data no programa, ele retorna a soma dessa coluna com os dados contendo a data digitada.

Fiz dessa forma mas não funcionou:

```
string query = "Select sum (quantidadeVagas) from vagas where data like '%" + mTxtDataVagas.Text + "%'";
MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection();

conexao.ConnectionString = DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao;
conexao.Open();

MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, conexao);
MySqlDataReader myReader;

myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    int quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(myReader.GetString("count"));
}
```

Aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: Código de erro]

Comment: O que não está funcionando? Ocorre um erro, não traz o resultado esperado? Dê mais detalhes por favor, para que possamos lhe ajudar. Se puder deixa um exemplo do resultado esperado e o modelo da sua tabela (nome dos campos e exemplo de uns 2 registros). Obrigado.

Comment: Eu editei com mais detalhes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque não adicionar um `MySqlParameter` ao `MySqlCommand` passando o valor da data?

```
string query = "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(quantidadeVagas), 0) AS Vagas FROM vagas WHERE data = @Data";

using(MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection(DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao))
{
    conexao.Open();

    using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, conexao))
    {
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", mTxtDataVagas.Text);

        using(MySqlDataReader myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int quantidade = 0;

            if(myReader.HasRows)
            {
                myReader.Read();
                quantidade = myReader.GetInt32("Vagas");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Da forma que estava a passar o parâmetro da data quase de certeza iria dar problemas.

Comment: Deu o erro: "Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()" no trecho: `quantidade = myReader.GetInt32("Vagas");`

Comment: Tem razão, faltou o `myReader.Read()`! Resposta editada.

Comment: Resposta editada. Provavelmente o erro dá por causa da atribuição do parâmetro. EDIT: como conseguiu ultrapassar o erro?

Comment: Eu havia trocado o `MySqlDbType.DateTime` por `MySqlDbType.VarChar`, mas perdurou se o valor é nulo

Comment: Como eu trato quando digita-se uma data que não está no banco de dados para que não retorne o erro: "Dados são Null. Não é possível chamar este método ou esta propriedade em valores Null."?

Comment: Resposta editada para evitar erro de nulos. Basicamente adicionar um `IFNULL` na _query_ SQL.

Answer (score 1):

O problema ocorre porque o MYSQL não aceita espaço em branco entre o nome da função e os parênteses, no caso está assim `sum (quantidadeVagas)`.

Altere sua query removendo o espaço em branco entre o `SUM` e os parênteses:

```
string query = "Select SUM(quantidadeVagas) from vagas where data like '%" + mTxtDataVagas.Text + "%'";
```